# Printing the tfidf matrix into a file

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to print the result of this tfidf process as (word, 2.333) in a text file. Currently it is printing it as all the words first and then the scores. How do I go about it? I also want the file to be sorted by idf value to get the most important words on top.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

results = []
with open("/Users/xyz/Documents/wholedata/X_tr.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        results.extend(line.strip().split('\n'))

blob=list(results)

vectorizer= TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)

X_train_tf=vectorizer.fit_transform(blob)
print(X_train_tf.shape)
idf=vectorizer._tfidf.idf_

p= (vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf)
with open("tfidf.txt","w") as t:
    for x in p:
        print>>t, x
```

Answer (score 2):

You could zip the two lists as

```
p = zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf)
```

sort the zipped list as

```
p.sort(key = lambda t: t[1])
```

Print them on console check and write them to a file.